# How while(array.length) works without any increment/decrement

Tags: javascript

Trying to solve **Basic Algorithm Scripting: Chunky Monkey** on FreeCodeCamp https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/chunky-monkey. Got stuck trying to fix my while loop and came across this code that works but I don't understand how the while loop `while (arr.length)` works  without any increment/decrement.

This is the code:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  var newArr = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: Array.splice modifies the array

Comment: `arr.splice` will change the length of the original array until it becomes zero and as zero is a falsy value, loop will break when `arr.length` is zero.

Comment: to your chunkArrayInGroups() function receiving the argument as arr . it is an Array  since array has length property

Comment: @Yousaf that makes perfect sense. I sometimes forget splice modifies the array. Thanks!